# Executing linux .sh file from Java with a parameter file as input and writing the output to .txt file

Tags: java, bash, shell, shellexecute, processbuilder

when I try in the linux shell to run the following shell script,

```
cd /home/fpalma/Project/resources/yices/linux64bit/
bash
chmod a+x yices
./yices /home/fpalma/Project/out/SMT.ys > /home/fpalma/Project/out/SMT.txt
```

it is running and generating the text file as output of that yices executable. But when I am running the same shell scripts from Java using the code,

```
String command = mainGUI.PROJECT_PATH+"resources/"+"yices.sh";
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
process.waitFor();
```

or

```
String command = mainGUI.PROJECT_PATH+"resources/"+"yices.sh";
pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = pb.start();
```

it is also running, but not exiting, and unless I am exiting the java compiler itself, it is not generating the text output file. Any suggestions???

Goal: my goal is to run a executable from java using a input paramater file and generate a output text file afterwards using '>' operator.

Comment: what purpose do your call to `bash` in the script-file has?

Comment: If your command produce a lot of output and you are not reading it it might stop execution until you read the output. try redirecting the output and/or read from the getInputStream() available on the process object (its connected to the ouput stream of the subprocess).

Answer (score 0):

your "command" variable should contain the full command, that is :
mainGUI.PROJECT_PATH+"resources/"+"yices.sh /home/fpalma/Project/out/SMT.ys > /home/fpalma/Project/out/SMT.txt"